# Is there a fast way to fingerprint a large number of files in python?

Tags: python, hash

I'm coding a program that has a function that compares file fingerprints (for files <5MB) and makes actions based on the data. The problem is that when scaling up to thousands of files it takes a relatively long time to process. The most recent test I ran took 75.7 seconds for 676 files, twice, so about 2 and a half minutes.

The main aim is to detect changes between a record of the directory tree (stored in a yaml file) and the two paths, or directory trees, so I can't seem to get around having to hash every file. Is there a way I can partially hash, or a faster method, or something else? Thanks.

Code of the fingerprinting function:

```
from hashlib import md5

BLOCK_SIZE = 65536

def fingerprinter(file_path):
    hash_method = md5()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as input_file:
        buf = input_file.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hash_method.update(buf)
            buf = input_file.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

    return hash_method.hexdigest()
```

A simplified version of the code that calls the fingerprint function:

```
def query(x_path):
    directory_tree = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x_path, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            if not "/." in root and not name.startswith("."):
                file_base = os.path.join(root, name) ## Root = path | Name = file
                print(file_base)
                hash = fingerprinter(file_base)
                media[file_base.split("/")[-1]] = {"hash": hash}

    return directory_tree
```

EDIT: [nevermind]

Comment: How long does it take when you remove the `hash_method.update(buf)`? How long if you change `hash = fingerprinter(file_base)` to `hash = 'foobar'`?

Comment: (1) Okay, so I ran the test a few times (including the original, just to compare). Strangely, it was going very slow the first few times, but pretty fast the last couple (I had to keep running, because I amended to output the data and make sure it was collecting the right data). I don't know why this would be, but it worked both times. As for the results: The original code: 8.75s. Your change: 0.692 seconds. I wonder if it's because I closed firefox those times? 

Anyway, it's a lot faster that way, thank you.

Comment: (2) I am checking the benchmark (using snakeviz) of specifically the "fingerprinter" method. The rest of the code only adds an overhead of ~3 seconds.

Comment: There are ways to monitor filesystem for file changes which I’d hve thought would be much less processor-intensive.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I considered creating a cache, which I have no experience with. From what I gathered, if I was running a process in the background I could detect changes (the cache would update), but I don't want to run in the background. Or, if I did something similar to saving a hash for a directory, it wouldn't be specific. I'm also would like to keep the code's footprint as small as possible (not create a lot of files or one over-long redundant one). Am I completely off-base in my assumptions?

Comment: Are the files in a specific format?  Knowledge of that format may make a "partial hash" possible - for example, there might be a timestamp or some such field in the header of each file that would necessarily change if the file was changed in any way.  That would allow you to hash just the header (or simply use the timestamp field instead of a hash).

Comment: So, I'm starting with audio and eventually other media. Currently in the actual code, it pulls the tags, filename, path and hash. I thought about using last modified (os.path.getmtime) and forgoing the fingerprint. However, that meant that while I gained time not hashing everything, it would lead to a net negative with performing file operations (deleting and copying the file VS shutil.move or os.rename, etc.). Also, the fingerprint allows me to identify a renamed file as the original, which getmtime wouldn't do.

Comment: I should say it pulls a couple uniquely identifying tags, not all of them.

Comment: Okay, hours later and I figured out the fatal flaw with the first comment. Every hash is the same now. Back to the drawing board. I also tried multiprocessing 'query' and only shaved a few seconds off. Also, I tried lru_cache and it was somehow slower. It just seems like easiest improvement is to have less things running, unfortunately.

Comment: Fishing for library recommendations is off-topic on StackOverflow. Go goggling for perhaps _linux monitor filesystem_ and you’ll get results.

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for another library, but I was detailing other methods I tried. I apologize if I was breaking the rules.